# How to fetch base URL in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I need the base url of my rails app in its code. Example if my site is [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) then i want this to be accessible in all controllers. Is there any method to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two step to archive :

1. According to [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/URL.html#method-i-domain), you can use `request.host` or `request.host_with_port` if you also need the port
2. You can use environment variable to store your BASE_URL, so that when you need to get your base url, you can call it like `ENV['BASE_URL']` either in the model, controller or view

You can use [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gem to help you manage your environment variable